# Microsoft Graph Api Onedrive sharing links missing users info

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When sharing a file on Onedrive with specific people the user got to connect using a one-time code.

How do I get those people allowed to use the shared link using the Microsoft Graph API?

Currently, the permission data only states the scope: "users", I was unable to find the users connected to the URL using the Graph Api.

This Info is available in the Onedrive UI itself.
[Users in the Onedrive UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JE52.png)

API Response for the same link:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('b***')/items('0***')/permissions/$entity",
"id": "***-c555beee2324",
"roles": [
    "read"
],
"link": {
    "scope": "users",
    "type": "view",
    "webUrl": "***qbagBM9ioYBhgkVqZx4blggM7Ow"
}
}
```

Comment: Below post will be helpful, please have a look. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754344/office-365-api-to-retrieve-external-users-list-from-anyonewithlink-shareable-lin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754344/office-365-api-to-retrieve-external-users-list-from-anyonewithlink-shareable-lin)